# Should we cut "so" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions, subordinate-clauses, run-on-sentences

> Ducks, geese, and swans are different types of waterfowl, but because they are similar in behavior and physical characteristics, **so** they comprise a single bird family.

I have to find an error in the sentence above.

The answer key says that we have to remove “ so” because  there are too many conjunctions. I don’t quite understand because I think we can still keep “so” in the sentence.

Do you think whether it is correct to remove “so” or it is possible to keep “ so “ in this sentence?

Comment: It's redundant with “because.”

Comment: Agree with Tyler. Also, removing *because* and replacing it with *as* makes better sense, doesn't it? We can certainly drop *so* in such case. *...types of waterfowl, but as they are similar in behavior and phsycial characteristics, they comprise a single bird.*

Comment: I get it now that it's redundant from Tyler's explaination. However, is it possible to remove "because" and keep "so"?

Comment: *...types of waterfowl, but they are similar in behavior and physical characteristics, they comprise a*... does not sound okay to me.

Comment: These two patterns are basically equivalent: *Because [cause], [consequence].* ~ *[Cause], so [consequence]*.

Comment: Thank you so much Damkerng! Your explanation is so useful! It's enlightening!

Comment: @nkm I think it would be fine to remove “because” and keep “so”.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I think you should write that up as an answer.

Comment: Yes, cut "so". With "but because" in the second part of the sentence, "so" is not necessary.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I agree with Tyler, you should answer! Regardless of picking out the grammatical error, though, the sentence itself confuses me. How are ducks, geese, and swans "a single bird"? They seem to be pretty distinctly 3 types of birds. (nkm, is there a source for this we can investigate further? I'm curious now.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions @WendiKidd & TylerJamesYoung. I will answer this question soon (within a day, I think). The missing key element is "family"; it should be "a single bird family".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatidae

Comment: @WendiKidd I have only those sentences from a test book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer

You should remove "so". Removing "because" is also possible but not recommended.

You can read more details below.

#### Conjunctions: 'so' and 'because'

*So* and *because* are both conjunctions, and both can be used to join two clauses together: a reason/cause clause with a result/consequence clause. Basically, these two patterns are equivalent:

> [Cause], *so* [consequence].
>   *Because* [cause], [consequence].

However, *so* and *because* work a little differently. *So* works as a **coordinating conjunction** to join two **independent clauses**. *Because* works as a **subordinating conjunction** to join a **subordinate clause** (or a dependent clause) to the main clause.

For example, consider these two sentences:

> *They had a test. They studied hard.*

We can join them with *so*. (Using *so* this way, you can read "so" as "it follows that". The result sentence is a **compound sentence**.)

> *They had a test, **so** they studied hard.*

We can also join them with *because*. (The result sentence is a **complex sentence**.)

> *They studied hard **because** they had a test.*
>   ***Because*** they had a test, they studied hard.

One subtle difference between the two is that *because* puts more emphasis on the reason, while *so* puts more emphasis on the consequence. Also, in a complex sentence, we can delete subordinate clauses without losing the main idea of the sentence because the main clause is still there. For example, *They studied hard <del>because they had a test</del>.*

#### How to fix the sentence

> *Ducks, geese, and swans are different types of waterfowl, but **because** they are similar in behavior and physical characteristics, **so** they comprise a single bird family.*

This sentence has three clauses:

> a) *Ducks, geese, and swans are different types of waterfowl.*
>   b) *They are similar in behavior and physical characteristics.*
>   c) *They comprise a single bird family.*

Using both *because* and *so* in the same sentence is considered incorrect. You can see the reason why clearly if we try to remove the subordinate clause. (Remember that a complex sentence will still make sense after having any subordinate clauses removed.)

> **Ducks, geese, and swans are different types of waterfowl, but <del>because they are similar in behavior and physical characteristics,</del> **so** they comprise a single bird family.*
>   
>   <sub>* denotes an incorrect usage</sub>

The sentence doesn't make sense anymore, and that is exactly why using both *because* and *so* in the same sentence is considered incorrect.

To fix that, we have two choices: remove either *because* or *so*. Both work fine, though I prefer removing *so* (and keeping *because*).

> d) *Ducks, geese, and swans are different types of waterfowl, but **because** they are similar in behavior and physical characteristics, they comprise a single bird family.*
>   f) *Ducks, geese, and swans are different types of waterfowl, **but** they are similar in behavior and physical characteristics, **so** they comprise a single bird family.*

(d) is correct. (f) is acceptable, but less preferred. The reason is that (f) contains three independent clauses. (f) has the structure *[A, but B, so C]*. This is perfectly fine in my opinion; however, because most compound sentences have only two independent clauses, some people might read a sentence having more than two independent clauses, (f) for example, as a run-on sentence.

#### References

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_clause
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-on_sentence

Comment: Thanks a lot for! I have to take time to learn and understand it.