# Can I use "but" and "because" in the same sentence?

Tags: conjunctions, negation

Example:

> One resident said the fine rain looked like snow **but** she couldn't be sure **because** this was the first time she had seen such a phenomenon.

Is the above sentence correct?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. Why do you think it might be wrong?

Comment: I want to use **'because'** in my sentence, **but** I don't know how to use it!

Comment: Yes it is correct, and in common usage, however "since" is slightly better.

Comment: @RuchirM, I think Alex wants to use 'because' in its actual usage. I wanted to give another example **but** I don't think an example would suffice **because** there might be a need to elaborate further.

Comment: @ThePhoton Actually, I have a problem about combining coordinating conjunctions and subordinate conjunctions togather

Comment: All you need is to understand that *but* and *because* are conjunctions of different kinds (given that you know independent clauses and subordinate/dependent clauses). I've answered a similar question [Should we cut “so” in this sentence?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/22002/3281) once, which may be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

That sentence is correct as-is, but it's easier to read if you add some commas:

> One resident said the fine rain looked like snow, but she couldn't be sure, because this was the first time she had seen such a phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is fine and, without your knowing it, you have balanced subordinate clauses and coordinate clauses.

Remember the acronym : **FANBOYS**

Where

- F _ FOR
- A _ AND
- N _ NOR
- B _ BUT
- O _ OR
- Y _ YET
- S _ SO.

They go with coordinate clauses and there is a handful of them as these.

Subordinating conjunctions are many. Always read the subordinate clause along with the subordinating conjunction. You will find that they not only link but also make the clause limp (dependent). Coordinates do not; they just link meaningfully. The clauses there are self sufficient.

Sorry for the digression but it may be of help to the poster.

- (that) the fine...snow
- because this... time
- (that/ when) she had...phenomenon

These are the subordinate clauses.

I find the compound sentence alright. Now you can also judge for yourself!

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/598864/2085).

Answer (score 0):

I also think it's right. " Because" is as the conjunction for the clause" She couldn't be sure" with the clause after it.

Answer (score 0):

One resident said the fine rain looked like snow but she could not be sure because this was the first time she had seen such a phenomenon.
To me it looks fine enough.